# Can Visual Studio list current preprocessor defines in intellisense?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I'm working in C#, in Visual Studio Community Edition 2015. When I type `#` the intellisense list appears, with an option for `#if`. If I type `#if` then nothing shows up in an intellisense list until I hit CTRL+Space and even then, the only things in the list are `true` and `false` even though there are many symbols defined, and Visual Studio knows about them, as it properly grays out code that is preprocessed out.

How can I have Visual Studio list all currently available preprocessor defines in the intellisense list for autocompleting after `#if`?

Comment: Either you have file-level defines, or you have project-level defines. The former are in the same file you are working; the latter in the project's properties. I don't think Intellisense show either.

Comment: The only reason VS shows `true`/`false` with CTRL+space is because those are the only language elements that are boolean at that scope.  I'm not aware of anything that auto-completes constants like that.  Maybe because you don't have to define them for them to work.  e.g. "#if SOMETHING" is syntactically correct even if SOMETHING is not defined in the project or the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS 2015 and 2017, when we define the complication symbols in file or properties page, the intellisense can only popups the true or false and it is by design, I found some other community members already reported this user voice to the VS product team, you can have a look at this user voice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/13348074-intellisense-for-c-conditional-compilation-symbol and vote it, then waiting for the response from the VS product team.

Comment: Ah. I came from Monodevelop where this functionality already exists, so I had assumed I was just missing something.